# identify Apache config directive

Tags: apache, centos

My website has a file: www.mydomain.com/contact.php

If I request any of the following (which do not exist), apache serves the contact.php page.
   www.mydomain.com/contact
   www.mydomain.com/contact/
   www.mydomain.com/contact/anything/else/here

How can I determine what part of the apache config to change to disallow this?

The apache server is running on a CentOS 5 box if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called `MultiViews`.

A `.htaccess` file or modifying your `httpd.conf` with `Options -MultiViews` should do the trick.